# If I don't care about insert speed, should I use S3 with Redshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a bunch of data I want to store and do analytics on. Based on pricing and data relationships, Redshift seems to be the right choice. However, I keep seeing things in the documentation and best practices that I should be using S3 and mass-copying my data into Redshift. Let's assume I don't care at all about insert-speed, and that I only care about the amount I'm paying for these services. If I use S3 and Redshift, I'm basically paying double, and I have more code to write. Why (financially) shouldn't I just insert my data directly using JDBC into Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the idea is that loading it directly to Redshift is going to take longer than loading to S3 + making RedShift pick it up from S3. 
So the math you have to do is: how long is it going to take to load it to Redshift? How much are you going to keep Redshift running (and pay for it ) while the load is in progress and you're not doing anything with the data?
How much are you paying if uploading to S3 and spinning up Redshift afterwards?
Going to guess (but remember it's a guess) that it's going to be slightly cheaper if you go through the S3.
Basically you want to use S3 for faster upload + the cost to store in S3 is marginal compared to how much Redshift costs and you can also use S3 as a source for other kind of processing you do on the data.

Comment: "So the math you have to do is: how long is it going to take to load it to Redshift?" Why do I have to know this? Do you know that this is a factor in calculating cost? If so, can you give a source? Thanks.

Comment: to load to redshift you need to have the instance running. That's anywhere beween 25c/hour and 6.8$/hour. Because the insert speed is super slow (per http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INSERT_30.html) you are going to pay a lot for the cluster until all the data is uploaded and you can use it. So, if using S3 you will pay for additional storage (per how much you store), if not using S3 you will pay more to keep the redshift cluster idle while loading. Redshift is way more expensive than S3 if your goal is to minimize cost.

Comment: "Redshift is way more expensive than S3 if your goal is to minimize cost." Are you saying that I could use just S3 and not use Redshift? I thought S3 was a key-store. I'm pretty sure it doesn't have a concept of sortkeys, which I need.

Comment: you can spin the redshift instance up and down and load from S3 whenever you need to. That may be cheaper. Not the normal usage pattern, but again seems you are interested in minimizing cost.